# Appending inside a parent tag using XmlWriter

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using this code to write to a xml document. Issue is every time I call this code it overrides previously written `Tags` element.

However I want to append multiple `Tag` elements inside the `Tags` elements. How can I make such sets using `XmlWriter`?

```
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path))
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Tags");
            writer.WriteElementString("Tag", tagName);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
```

I found out over the net few solution involving LINQ, with which I am not very good at. So I am looking something without it?

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like you're creating a new XmlWriter each time you call that snippet. You will need to split that up into a function that creates the writer and append the document element and one that appends a new child node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via Linq Xml by:

```
public void AddTagToXml(string path, string tag)
{
    XDocument doc;

    // Load the existing file
    if (File.Exists(path)) doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    else
    {
        // Create a new file with the parent node
        doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Tags"));
    }

    doc.Root.Add(new XElement("tag", tag));

    doc.Save(path);
}
```

It's not terribly efficient as the file is opened and saved on each function call, but it covers your requirements.